# Why wrap around is necessary for queue but not for stack?

Tags: data-structures

I know that wrap around is used in queue so we don't need to move each element when deleting or inserting another element, but why we can't do that in the stack too?

Answer (score 2):

Because a [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) is last in, first out (LIFO); that is, we remove from the same end that we insert on. As such, the first position in the array will only be unused when the stack is empty.